# Unable Join SOME 64 bit Windows 8.1 Pro Clients to Windows Sever 2003 Domain

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain, windows-8.1

We just deployed 12 brand new Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit client machines.  They are all identical models and all wired identically to our network/server room.  8 of the machines joined the domain with no problem by the simple method of changing the Domain in In the computer properties page.  Cant get the other 4 to join the domain with ANY method.  Get the error, "the domain does not exist, or the domain cannot be contacted."

- All of the machines are named with the same convention, sequentially, and all of the DNS and TCP/IP settings match.  All auto assigned.
- I can ping the server from the computers which wont join the domain, and I can also map network drives from the machines which will not join the domain.
- I have tried using FQDN.
- I have tried manually adding the machines to the AD.  I also have removed all obsolete computers from the AD.
- In the AD, I have gotten an error message about improper naming even though the name convention is the same as the computers which joined the domain with no problem.
- There is no antivirus running on these machines yet, and I have also tried disabling the firewall, without success.
- These computers are also running a client application which accesses a different server on our network, and they all have full functionality with that application.

Next step to troubleshoot this?  Did I miss someting simple?

I am not a professional Network Admin, I have pretty basic knowledge of Windows networking, how to join domain, and basic management of AD and Windows Clients.

Comment: `In the AD, I have gotten an error message about improper naming` - Where are you seeing that message?

Comment: Could you paste the txt of the improper naming error into here?  It might be helpful.

Comment: You can try temporarily disabling the firewall for both the DC and client machines.

Comment: @CarlosRichardPrado: `1.` The OP has already tried that. `2.` That shouldn't be necessary to join a computer to the domain. I've never had to disable the DC or client firewall for the hundreds of domain joins I've done throughout my IT career.

Comment: I have gotten one of the machines to join the domain.  Havent tried the others yet.
Had to specify a preferred DNS address in TCP/IPV4 in my internet adapter settings.
However, now the shared network drives for the user on the domain show up in the computer but disconnected.  
Get the message "The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request.  Please try again later"
If I try to access the network drive, it prompts for credentials and once entered the network resource is available and stays so until user logs off.

Comment: So, users technically have access to their network resources on the client machines when logged in, but its a bit tedious as it requires multiple logins.  
Im not sure what the step is to have the DC automatically authenticate the user when they log in to the domain?

Comment: Just to clarify: Is the DC also the DNS server for the domain? If so, are all clients configured to only use that server for DNS?

Comment: The DC is the DNS server for the domain.  As far as I can tell, they should only use that server for DNS.  All of the machines which joined the domain as expected were configured for automatically assigned IP addresses and DNS addresses. 
There is a client application on each machine which points to a different server's IP address which is set up right in the client software and doesnt require any modifications in any windows networking settings on any local machines. That server is not connected to the domain.